# "Devant de" vs "au-devant de" vs "au devant de" ?

Tags: grammaire

I was looking at [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Sphinx_of_Giza#mediaviewer/File:Norden,_1755_(1).png), a hundreds-of-years-old sketch of the Sphinx's face, and noticed the author wrote *Elle est au devant de la seconde Pyramide.* I thought it was *devant de*, or even just *devant*, not *au devant de*....is that usage outdated, or am I simply mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally *au-devant de* (with an hyphen) means something like "coming toward" (French *à la rencontre de*), but Grevisse (Le *Bon Usage*, 14r ed., §1073(a)1°) notes that the meaning "in front of" is also found and listed in the *Trésor de la langue Française* ([here,](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devant) in the subs. masc. entry, under sense C) but not in the *Robert* or the Academie's dictionary, and calls it "rare", that is also my feeling: strongly literary (as such rare usages tend to sound).